# KeyPressed letter validation and KeyEvent combination input limit not working

Tags: java, keyevent

I need to enter a name and the textfield should accept letters and until 100 characters only so I used KeyPressed and put a letter validation as well as the input number of characters limit but when I run it, I can also input numbers and it doesn't have an input number of characters limit.

Also, I have an address field too and it doesn't need validation because it can accept both letters and numbers but there's also a 100 characters input number of characters limit. I also used KeyPressed for this one but I tried it with KeyTyped but it doesn't work as well. I ran the program and I can input any characters but it doesn't have an input number of characters limit.

This is my code for the name:

```
private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
String jj = jTextField1.getText();
int len = jj.length();
char ts = evt.getKeyChar();

if (Character.isLetter(ts) || Character.isWhitespace(ts) || Character.isISOControl(ts))
{
    jTextField1.setEditable(true);
}
else
{
    jTextField1.setEditable(false);
}

if (evt.getKeyChar()>='0' && evt.getKeyChar()<='9')
{
    if (len<100)
    {
        jTextField1.setEditable(true);
    }
    else
    {
        jTextField1.setEditable(false);
    }
}
```

}

and this is my code for the address:

```
private void jTextField3KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    String jj = jTextField1.getText();
    int len = jj.length();
    char ts = evt.getKeyChar();

    if (evt.getKeyChar()>='0' && evt.getKeyChar()<='9')
    {
        if (len<100)
        {
            jTextField1.setEditable(true);
        }
        else
        {
            jTextField1.setEditable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't make the field uneditable.  Just make sure that any String over 100 characters is truncated to 100 characters.

Comment: i'm really sorry but how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to limit the number of characters typed into a field is to limit the size of the field.

I created this GUI to show you how to limit an address to 100 characters.

[image: Address GUI]

I used a `JTextArea` for the address since an address can contain up to three lines.  Normally, you'd make the `JTextArea` character width something like 30.  I made it 70 so you could see what the `LimitDocumentFilter` class does.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class AddressFieldLimit implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new AddressFieldLimit());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Address Field Limit");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Address:");
        innerPanel.add(label);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(3, 70);
        LimitDocumentFilter limitfilter = new LimitDocumentFilter(100);
        ((PlainDocument) textArea.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(limitfilter);
        innerPanel.add(textArea);

        panel.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);

        return panel;
    }

    public class LimitDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        private int maxLength;

        public LimitDocumentFilter(int maxLength) {
            this.maxLength = maxLength;
        }

        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, 
                int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()) <= this.maxLength)
                super.insertString(fb, offset, str, attr);
            else
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, 
                int offset, int length, String str, AttributeSet attrs)
                throws BadLocationException {
            if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()) <= this.maxLength)
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, str, attrs);
            else
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
        
    }

}
```